# Sorting an ArrayList in Java using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, arraylist, binary-tree

I want to sort an ArrayList in Java using a Threads Binary Tree.
The problem is as follows:

> The main method creates the first node passing a randomly generated list. Every node behaves the same way. If the list has 0 or 1 elements, it returns. Otherwise, it creates two new nodes passing them the two halfes of the list. Once the child nodes have sorted their lists, the parent node merges them keeping them sorted.

And this is the code I have written so far...
But I can't get it to work ! It keeps on printing the list unsorted in the end.
And thank you very much in advance.

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int size = rnd.nextInt(90) + 1 + 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add(rnd.nextInt(100));
        }

        Node n = new Node(list);
        n.start();

        try {
            n.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("The sorted list:\n" + list.toString());
    }
}
```

**Node.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node extends Thread {
    private List<Integer> list;

    public Node(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (list.size() <= 1)
            return;

        List<Integer> l1, l2;
        l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        add(l1, 0, list.size() / 2);
        add(l2, list.size() / 2, list.size());

        Node a, b;
        a = new Node(l1);
        b = new Node(l2);
        a.start();
        b.start();

        try {
            a.join();
            b.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        merge(l1, l2);
    }

    private void add(List<Integer> l, int from, int to) {
        l.addAll(list.subList(from, to));
    }

    private void merge(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int size1 = l1.size();
        int size2 = l2.size();

        int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, n1, n2;
        while (i1 < size1 && i2 < size2) {
            n1 = l1.get(i1);
            n2 = l2.get(i2);

            if (n1 <= n2) {
                list.add(n1);
                i1++;
            } else {
                list.add(n2);
                i2++;
            }
        }

        while (i1 < size1) {
            list.add(l1.get(i1++));
        }

        while (i2 < size2) {
            list.add(l2.get(i2++));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't seeing the original `List` in a merged state, because the first thing you do in your `merge()` method is throw away the reference you were holding of the original `List`:

```
private void merge(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ...
```

All of the actual merging of sorted data is happening in the new `List` you've made, but you're printing the original, unsorted `List` in your `main()` method.

You need to either sort the elements of the original `List`, or return the (new) sorted one somehow.

Comment: Holy ****, that's it... list.clear(); instead of reinstantiating made it ! Thank you.